# Is it possible to use self hosted Nancy with https (ECDH-ECDSA) on Linux (Mono)?

Tags: c#, https, mono, nancy, self-hosting

The software I'm working on  will run on an embedded system running Linux. We are currently in a hardware evaluation phase so the OS will either be Debian or a stripped-down buildroot Linux (presumably it's going to be this one). I managed to get [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) up and running but now the requirement arose to use TLS with ECDH-ECDSA.

The official documentation only offers an [example configuration for Windows](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Accessing-the-client-certificate-when-using-SSL) using netsh (which I unfortunately cannot test since I'm not allowed to execute netsh commands on my machine). While researching, I found other sources ([here](https://coderead.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/enabling-ssl-for-self-hosted-nancy/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553633/nancyfx-self-hosting-over-https)) which are also only true for Windows.

There is also [a rather old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320348) stating that "Nancy console hosting doesn't support ssl itself, so in order to have ssl, you need to run another web server, which does support ssl". And indeed, there is a documentation for using [Nancy with Nginx on Ubuntu](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu). Since the buildroot Linux has no package manager it is hardly (if at all) possible to install Nginx on the system. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716988) stating to use `httpcfg` to bind a certificate to a port. But again, `httpcfg` is not available on the buildroot Linux system, altough it might be possible to get it installed if available.

So, is it possible to use self hosted Nancy with https (ECDH-ECDSA) on Linux (Mono) without running another web server?
If so, how can I accomplish this and how can I tell Nancy to use TLS with ECDH-ECDSA?